# uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby, controller, netbeans6.7

I'm trying to do this tutorial-> http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ruby/rapid-ruby-weblog.html

BUT

its giving me this error:

NameError in PostsController#index

uninitialized constant PostsController::Posts

I don't know whats wrong

Comment: when i right-click on the project and test it tells me that PostsControllerTest failed because "Unknown database 'project_test'"

Comment: You can create the test database with `rake environment=test db:create`

Comment: The link in the question is broken. It was better to post the issue in full.

Answer (score 12):

Somewhere in the files processed for your action you have tried to use a class called `Posts`. Try using `Post` instead of `Posts`. There is no Posts class. You are probably looking for the Post model class.

Look for the mistake in either in the index method of `posts_controller.rb` or in `app/views/posts/index.html.erb`. The error message should help you find the offending line.